# How to write a file to second sector of a disk using dd?

Tags: windows, dd

I am using dd In a windows environment. I know to write a file to the 1st sector of a disk using the command,

```
dd if=c:\... of=c:\... bs=512 count=1
```

How to write a file or data to the second sector of a disk using dd?

Comment: Presumably this is about how to test your code you have written. Generic system administration questions otherwise belong on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

To write to the second sector, use these two options `seek=1 count=1`

Also, note that in your example the `if` and `of` parameters are probably wrong. If you are trying to read and write DISKS, if`and`of`values would probably start with`/dev/` (depending on what OS you are). Your c:... looks like a beginning of a Windows file name. This may fine, if you are using a Windows port of dd and it accepts file names in this format, but even in this case, they are not DISK names, they are FILE names.